# Finding minimum fly-by radius between Mars and spacecraft from interpolating function

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation, astronomy

I've written an interplanetary trajectory solver/plotter that plots the path taken by a spacecraft on an Earth-Mars mission, but have run into a little trouble when the spacecraft actually reaches Mars. I'm hoping to be able to get the spacecraft into an orbit around Mars upon arrival, but before I can do that I need to find its closest approach in order to apply the correct delta-v at the right time (using the wonders of NDSolve's WhenEvent function). The trajectory plot relies on the output of an interpolating function from NDSolve, and it is this interpolating function that I am trying to work with. So far I know when the closest approach occurs to within a day, and it is between days 254 and 255 of the trip. I have put the Heliocentric x-y positions of Mars and the spacecraft (between days 254 and 255) into separate tables using the following:

```
MarsPosition = Table[{x[2][t], y[2][t]} /. Soln, {t, 254*86400, 255*86400, 86400/100}] 
SpaceCraftPosition = Table[{x[3][t], y[3][t]} /. Soln, {t, 254*86400, 255*86400, 86400/100}]
```

And have then calculated their relative x-y positions using the following:

```
dxy = Sqrt[(MarsPosition - SpaceCraftPosition)^2]
```

But I am now trying to calculate the minimum approach radius (i.e. combining the x-y positions into a magnitude) from the above bits of code. My futile attempt of trying

```
dr = Min[Sqrt[dxy[1]^2 + dxy[2]^2]]
```

and other similar attempts have unfortunately ended in failure. Some sample output looks like this:

```
  dxy = {{{2.00946*10^8, 9.69241*10^7}}, {{2.03432*10^8, 
       9.83663*10^7}}, {{2.05917*10^8, 9.98081*10^7}},...}
```

Where, for example, the first entry shows the x and y relative position as `{2.00946*10^8, 9.69241*10^7}` and I'm trying to combine those two components into a radius. Combining the x-y position pairs into a radius using `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]` for the first 3 position pairs given above I would get

```
 dr = {{2.231*10^8},{2.25965*10^8},{2.2883*10^8},...}
```

But this was done manually for each entry and is not practical for hundreds of entries. From this list of radius positions, I can then use `Min[]` to find the closes approach point for the spacecraft relative to Mars.

As can be seen below, the spacecraft gets very close to Mars (where the inner semi-circle is Earth's orbit, the outer semi-circle is Mars' orbit and the line joining the two is the spacecraft's trajectory):[image]

And if propagated further we can see that it gets close enough for Mars' gravity to affect its trajectory:[image]

So it looks pretty close, but exactly how close it what I'm hoping to find out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to give us `Soln` first or all your flybys are belong to us :D  PS: Look up `Norm`.

Comment: I was hoping someone would know a general way to work with tables where each entry gives an x-y position pair. I can give the code for Soln if needed, but it is a ton of code what will take some time to edit into a "stackexchange friendly" format.

Comment: yeah, but *some* data to work with would be great, otherwise (how) are we supposed to make that up? Did you already look up `Norm` or `Nearest`?

Comment: I would think you would be able to use `Soln` and `FindMinimum`.  You could probably find the closest point with `WhenEvent`, too, if `Soln` is produced by `NDSolve`.  Hard to tell.

Comment: Very true, my apologies, I've edited the original post and given some example output for the first 3 x-y position pairs from the `dxy` table as well as what I hope to get as a table for `dr`. Doing that now I realise that I should have just give a general example in the first place instead of writing out what I'm using it for.

Comment: See the three-body example in [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html#57647503).  They use `WhenEvent` to find the max. distance.  You could do something similar.

Comment: Yeah it's a good `WhenEvent` application. However, the original differential equation is needed, which has not been provided here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'll answer my own question in case someone else needs to use it for future reference. The following code was used to find the minimum approach radius:

```
    MarsPosition = Table[{x[2][t], y[2][t]} /. Soln, {t, 253*86400, 256*86400, 60}] ;
    SpaceCraftPosition = Table[{x[3][t], y[3][t]} /. Soln, {t, 253*86400, 256*86400, 60}] ;
    (*xy positions for spacecraft relative to Mars*)
    dxy = Sqrt[(MarsPosition - SpaceCraftPosition)^2];
    (*Table used to hold approach radii*)
    dr = Table[Norm[dxy[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[dxy]}]
    (*Minimum approach radius*)
    mindr = Min[dr]
    (*Index position at which mindr occurred*)
    mindrindex = Position[dr, mindr]
    (*Time at which mindr occurred, t = (253 days + 60n seconds), where n is the index of mindr*)
    mindrtime = (253*86300) + (60*mindrindex)
```

Thanks for trying to help Yves and Michael, I appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome! Only without incomplete code to this question will only be partially helpful. You could add in some test data to make it that much better (and get some more rep).

Comment: Yup, I agree it was very vague. I have edited it to include test data for the `dxy` table.